# Do untamed dogs have collars?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was wondering around my MCPE world when I came across this pack of dogs that are not tamed to me or my sister because she is the only person that has ever came in that world but she never tamed any dogs, They have white collars (this is in the update where you can dye dogs collars) and I'm wondering if its normal.

Answer (score 1):

They have a collar because it's the same entity as a tamed dog but it can't be edited in any way as you would with a tamed dog (using dye)

The only difference between tamed and untamed dogs in the code is that tamed dogs can have their collar painted and that they can sit down and teleport to the player.

The untamed tog just has an `undefined` color variable as it's collar color that displays the same color as the rest of the dog. Therfor it looks like it's not there

Answer (score -2):

Untamed dogs have no collars. It might be your sister who has tamed the dogs without your consent.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ChargingPun Why? It gives an answer "Untamed dogs have no collars"

Answer (score -2):

Untamed dogs do not have collars. The dogs themselves are white and grey, so I don't think it's a collar. When you tame the dog, the collars are automatically red, and I don't think you can sue the collars yet.

Answer (score -2):

I've seen this in my game as well, and it's definetly not the color of the dog because they are sitting and I was able to dye the collar yellow. I've found them at random places all around the world, and none of them are tamed to me.